# Align button in the center of a table and in the center of the button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, alignment, center

I made a table that holds a button and i want the button in the center of the table.

The problem is that the button is aligning not in the center of the button but aligning when the button starts, so the button is a little far to the right, here is an image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
       <table  width="100%"  border="0px" style="background:transparent">
       <tr>
        <td height="305px">



      <%-- button---%>
       <div style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="#" class="btn"  >Conocer más</a>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

and here is the css.

```
.btn{
background-color:#44c767;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #18ab29;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:17px;
padding:16px 31px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #2f6627;
position: absolute;

}
```

The other problem I am having is I can't align it vertically inside the table.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the code that centers your button horizontally and vertically. I tweaked the style a little because I don't think you need an absolute position and a display block for your button. But if that messes up with the rest of your page we can still do it wrapping the button inside another div. Let me know.

**The vertical alignment is done by setting the line-height of your div with the same height of your TD.**

HTML code:

```
<table  width="100%"  border="1" style="background:transparent">
<tr>
    <td style="height:305px;">
        <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;line-height:305px;">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Conocer más</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS code:

```
.btn {
    background-color: #44c767;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #18ab29;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 16px 31px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

When you have some time try to convert that page using only divs. I think you can easily accomplish it without tables at all.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried adding a width value and then using

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

in your button css.  This should just move the button to the centre of its parent div.  Hope this helps :)